# Sum number of record between dates Excel

Tags: excel, date

I need to count the number of record between two dates.

I've tried this but it doesn't work.

Column A is a list of dates

```
E3 start date
E4 end date

=sumif(A:A;">="&E3;"<="&E4)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNTIFS should do the trick:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A;">="&E3;A:A;"<="&E4)
```

EDIT: corrected an obvious mistake. Thanks for comments. Change `;` to `,` depending on your regional settings.

Comment: You beat me by 4s : )